# solr proximity search while using OR operator

Tags: solr, lucene

Is it possible to make a proximity query in solr while using OR operator, example:

term1:"Samsung"
term2:"galaxy note" OR "galaxy 3" OR ...

i need to find if i have both term1 and term2 with ~n proximity.

Comment: Your case doesn't make sense.  You can have a proximity query across two fields.  You are searching across fields "term1" and "term2".  I'm not really sure what proximnity would mean across separate fields.  Can you explain what this is supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry the example i gave can be confused with solr-lucene query conventions. term1 and term2 are not to be read as fields. Please read it as: how can i find if term1 and term2 with ~n proximity and term1 is "Samsung" and term2 is "galaxy note" OR "galaxy 3" OR ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by default in Solr 4.4 which is currently the latest version.

[SOLR-1604](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1604) has some relevant information.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is SOLR-1604 patche is compatible with Solr 4.4.0 ? Recompiling solr gives BUILD FAILD.

Comment: No, its not compatible by default but you can try to update the patch for 4.4 yourself - should not be too hard. Also, I don't think you need to recompile Solr - the code there creates a separate jar file which you need to add to the `lib` folder of Solr.

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach here would be to just generate a set of longer phrase queries, so rather that looking for "Samsung" and "galaxy note" separately, you concatenate them together, to give you something more like:

```
"Samsung galaxy note" OR "Samsung galaxy 3" ...
```

and setting it to have the desired amount of slop.

You can also use [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html)  which handles similar cases, though I'm not sure it handles alternate phrases within a phrases.  [SurroundQueryParser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SurroundQueryParser) also supports this sort of thing, but doesn't do any analysis, which means you'll have to analyze your subqueries before hand (see the Limitations section in the documentation).

If you want to manually generate queries, you can support this more directly using a set of [`SpanQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanQuery.html)s, which would look something like:

```java
Query rootQuery = parser.parse("\"Samsung\"");
Query option1Query = parser.parse("\"galaxy note\"");
Query option2Query = parser.parse("\"galaxy 3\"");
Query option3Query = parser.parse("\"something else\"");
SpanQuery orQuery = new SpanOrQuery(
    new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(option1Query), 
    new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(option2Query), 
    new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(option3Query)
);
SpanQuery finalQuery = new SpanNearQuery({new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(rootQuery), orQuery}, slop, true);
```